# Facebook login causing java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

Tags: heroku, playframework, play-authenticate

we are working on a Java application built with PlayFramework and deploying it to Heroku. We integrate our login mechanism with Facebook through Play Authenticate, but since this morning, we are not able to log in. We get some secure certificate exception that looks like the attached one.

We were wondering if that might be due some change in the environment, since we don't recall changing any related application code. Is there something we can check?

Thanks in advance,

```
2013-02-20T17:33:32+00:00 app[web.1]: play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty]]
2013-02-20T17:33:32+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-02-20T17:33:32+00:00 app[web.1]: at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:383) [play_2.10-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
2013-02-20T17:33:32+00:00 app[web.1]: at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) [play_2.10-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
2013-02-20T17:33:32+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:508) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
2013-02-20T17:33:32+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:759) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
2013-02-20T17:33:32+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:727) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
2013-02-20T17:33:32+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1118) ~[netty-3.5.9.Final.jar:na]
2013-02-20T17:33:32+00:00 app[web.1]: at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
2013-02-20T17:33:32+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
2013-02-20T17:33:32+00:00 app[web.1]: at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anon$2$$anonfun$handle$1.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:132) [play_2.10-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
2013-02-20T17:33:32+00:00 app[web.1]: at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) [play_2.10-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
2013-02-20T17:33:32+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
2013-02-20T17:33:32+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.(PKIXValidator.java:75) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
2013-02-20T17:33:32+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.security.validator.Validator.getInstance(Validator.java:178) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
2013-02-20T17:33:32+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:270) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
2013-02-20T17:33:32+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:225) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
2013-02-20T17:33:32+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
2013-02-20T17:33:32+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.setTrustAnchors(PKIXParameters.java:200) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
2013-02-20T17:33:32+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.security.cert.PKIXBuilderParameters.(PKIXBuilderParameters.java:104) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
2013-02-20T17:33:32+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.(PKIXParameters.java:120) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
2013-02-20T17:33:32+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.(PKIXValidator.java:73) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
2013-02-20T17:33:32+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1147) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
2013-02-20T17:33:32+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.security.validator.Validator.getInstance(Validator.java:178) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
2013-02-20T17:33:32+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.getValidator(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
```

Comment: After some time troubleshooting the issue, a colleague pushed new changes to the app and redeployed.
Nothing seems to be related to the log in issue, but it's now working.
Might it have to do with where the new application was started? Something to do with the previous deploy? Is there any log from the deploy process we can check for the last one?

Comment: Sorry for the trouble this caused you. We updated the JDK last night and it was missing the default cacerts file. We've since rolled it back, which is why you're not seeing the problem anymore.

Comment: Hi Naaman, thanks for the answer, great to know what it was!

Comment: Looks like this issue has reappeared today. I am experiencing this same scenario. Also, my slug size is suddenly ~80MB larger with minor code changes (no new dependencies)...

Comment: Same here I just redeployed today and now I am getting this error

Answer (score 1):

From Naaman answer, it was due to a JDK update.